# Blank space with frames

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, frame

So, I have created a page with 3 frames, top, left and right where left meant to be main and content frame where right frame meant to be index.

Here is how it looks on opera/nightly/even ie:
[image: nondescript]
yet, this is how it looks on chrome:
[image: nondescript]
see white space after blue, under green. it looks even uglier when you use black.

I wish i could give you jsfiddle or something but it doesnt work for frames, and problem only happens in chrome. the html code is located at http://pastebin.com/HxG4NUjb and cant paste here because alth. I use four spaces, this editor seems to think its just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enclosing the frame `id="ma"` inside another extra frameset. Remove the extra frameset and that'll get rid of the extra white space.

Change this...

```
<frameset id="x" rows="50,*" border = "0" frameborder ="0">
<frame id="to" name="to" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" style="frameborder:0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
        <frameset cols="*,200" border="0">
        <frame id="ri" name="ri" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" />
                <frameset cols="200,*" style="border:0">
                <frame id="ma" name="ma" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" frameborder="0"  noresize="noresize" />  
                </frameset>
        </frameset>
</frameset>
```

to this...

```
<frameset id="x" rows="50,*" border = "0" frameborder ="0">
    <frame id="to" name="to" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" style="frameborder:0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
    <frameset cols="*,200" border="0">
        <frame id="ri" name="ri" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" />
        <frame id="ma" name="ma" src="http://examancer.com/mobile/screen.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" />  
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```